# vertical scrollable CCLayerColor issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i'm trying to do a scrollable layer with cocos2d

what i want is for the layer to start scrolling from the top to bottom but no matter what i do when it enters the scene the layer is positioned at (0,0) aka..bottom

i've tried a couple of things but nothing seems to work

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        isDragging = NO;
        yvel = 0.0f;
        contentHeight = 1000.0f;

        scrollLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(200, 200, 200, 240)];
        scrollLayer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,contentHeight);
        scrollLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);
        scrollLayer.position = ccp(0, 480);
        [self addChild: scrollLayer];


        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test label"]
                                                   fontName:@"Marker Felt"
                                                   fontSize:24];

        label.position=ccp(100, 100);

        [scrollLayer addChild:label];


        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

the other methods are update and touches handlers so the problem couldn't be there

with this code...shouldn't it initialize with the content at the top left of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a painful few hours i finally solved the problem...but i still dont know why it works

instead of   `scrollLayer.position = ccp(0, 480);`  i replaced with  `scrollLayer.position =ccp(0,-contentHeight);` and deleted `scrollLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0,1);` cuz it wasnt doing anything

and i have absolutely no idea why it works

can someone explain this?